# How to design Java Contract class for an Employee

Tags: java, class, oop

I am designing a class for an employee management system.
Class Employee has following fields:

```
:Employee  
id:int  
firstName:String  
lastName:String  
contract:Contract
```

Class Contract has following fields:

```
:Contract  
-contractNo:int  
-contractDate:Date  
-contractType:Type  
-rate:Double  
-function:Function  
-contractCopy:File
```

When an individual becomes employed within the company, he/she signs a contract with an agreed rate, function etc.  From time to time, management revises the contract and changes rate and/or function.

Could somebody advise how to design a class that stores revisions of the contract? The user needs to view the original information and all revisions.

Answer (score 2):

You already have two nice entities to create classes for: `Contract` and `Employee`, both of which also make nice tables to store data.

I would create a `ContactRevision` class, that has fields of the `Contract` that can be revised.

For example:

```
:ContactRevision
  -contractType
  -rate
  -modifiedOn
  -modifiedBy
```

You could then add a property to your `Contract` entity called `revisions` of type `List<ContractRevisions>`, with operations like `addRevision` or `getAllRevisions` to show the changed values if desired.

Comment: Disagree. A more general approach would be to change `Contract` to store a revision number, and save every revision as a new row in `Contract`.  That way if later you decide to change something besides rate or function, no additional database work is required.  Every revision stands on its own and no separate table is needed.

Comment: Ahh, but you forget one thing..history. If you change the structure of the contract where a modified field has been changed or no longer exists in Contract, then you lose the history of that change. ContactRevision shows a snapshot at a moment in time that 'something' was changed on the Contract. Also, Contract is likely a heavily used table and storing many revisions of the same contract leads to poor performance and  complicate the queries to get at the data in a typical case. I would store the original value before changed in ContractRevision. Contract would always store the latest values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Event Sourcing Pattern. It will allow you to track the change history.

In short you create an event for each change and thanks to this you may review it whenever you want.

You can find more information here:

- http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589792.aspx

Comment: I found very less information on web for implementation this pattern with Java. The more information i found about Memento design patter. Is Memento patter not better for this case: tracking revisions of contract?